# How to get logged-in user's name in Access vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way for MS Access to grab the current Active Directory user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052/is-there-a-way-for-ms-access-to-grab-the-current-active-directory-user)

I want to get the name of the logged-in User via [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) in [access](/questions/tagged/access). What is the best way to do this?

---

Duplicates of this question:

- [Is there a way for MS Access to grab the current Active Directory user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052/is-there-a-way-for-ms-access-to-grab-the-current-active-directory-user)
- [Using VB6, how do I get the current user and domain on Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337237/using-vb6-how-do-i-get-the-current-user-and-domain-on-windows-xp/337374)
- [How can I get the currently logged-in windows user in Access VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168659/how-can-i-get-the-currently-logged-in-windows-user-in-access-vba/168682)
- [Excel 2007 VBA and WMI - Current DOMAIN\USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287369/excel-2007-vba-and-wmi-current-domain-user)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" 
    Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

....

```
Dim strLen As Long
Dim strtmp As String * 256
Dim strUserName As String

strLen = 255
GetUserName strtmp, strLen
strUserName = Trim$(TrimNull(strtmp))
```

Turns out question has been asked before: [How can I get the currently logged-in windows user in Access VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168659/how-can-i-get-the-currently-logged-in-windows-user-in-access-vba/168682)

Comment: I didn't see that the question has been asked before. Thanks, anyways

Comment: Be aware that `Declare` is not available in 64-bit Access.

Comment: Can you show your code for `TrimNull`?

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment.

Answer (score 50):

Try this:

```
Function UserNameWindows() As String
     UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this can be changed by users/applications...

Comment: It might not be 100% secure every time, but let's be honest, we're talking about VBA. I for one, choose the easy way :)

Comment: @Eric +1 Here.  If you're that concerned, you shouldn't be using Access in the first place.

Comment: Perfect. This works great for me; I don't give a crap if it's not 9001% secure. Thanks man!

Answer (score -3):

In a Form, Create a text box, with in text box properties select data tab

```
Default value =CurrentUser()
```

Current source "select table field name"

It will display current user log on name in text box / label as well as saves the user name in the table field

Comment: This does not display the current user's name; it returns the "name of the current user of the database".  This defaults to "Admin" unless you've established a security-enabled workgroup.