# Updating Access VBA code for listing Active Directory memberships

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory

My employer has recently upgraded from Office 2010 to 2016, and I need to update some VBA code to accommodate 64 bit MS Access. The code checks the user's Active Directory memberships to confirm what modules they are allowed access to. I've made some progress, but am stumbling on the section below:

```
Private Function fStringFromPtr(lngPtr As LongPtr) As String
    Dim lngLen As LongPtr
    Dim abytStr() As Byte

    lngLen = apiStrLenFromPtr(lngPtr) * 2
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)
        Call apiCopyMemory(abytStr(0), ByVal lngPtr, lngLen)
        fStringFromPtr = abytStr()
    End If
End Function
```

Specifically, the problem appears to be the "ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)" instruction. This has been resulting in a Type Mismatch error. I've made several attempts to change the abytStr variable type, but the results are always the same.

This code has been working for several years without a problem on the 32 bit version. Can anyone see a reason why this wouldn't work under 64 bit?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, here's the full code set I'm working with.

First off, here's the code that works under 32 bit Access 2010:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim m_strGroups() As String         'Cache with all security groups this user is a member of.

Private Type WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
   wkui1_username As Long     'current user name
   wkui1_logon_domain As Long 'current user domain
   wkui1_oth_domains As Long  'list of other LAN Manager domains browsed by the workstation
   wkui1_logon_server As Long 'name of the computer that authenticated the server
End Type

Private Declare Function apiWkStationUser Lib "Netapi32" Alias "NetWkstaUserGetInfo" (ByVal reserved As Long, ByVal Level As Long, bufptr As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function apiStrLenFromPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenW" (ByVal lpString As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub apiCopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
Private Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function getLoginName() As String
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim lpBuff As String * 255

    ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 255)

    If ret > 0 Then
        getLoginName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        getLoginName = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Public Function getUserDomain() As String
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim lngPtr As Long
    Dim tNTInfo As WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
    Dim strNTDomain As String

    lngRet = apiWkStationUser(0&, 1&, lngPtr)
    If lngRet = 0 Then
        Call apiCopyMemory(tNTInfo, ByVal lngPtr, LenB(tNTInfo))
        If Not lngPtr = 0 Then
            strNTDomain = fStringFromPtr(tNTInfo.wkui1_logon_domain)
        End If
    End If

Exit_Handler:
getUserDomain = strNTDomain
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    strNTDomain = vbNullString
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Public Function GetSecurityGroups() As String()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    CacheSecurityGroups

Exit_Handler:
    GetSecurityGroups = m_strGroups
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

'   Fills array with all Active Directory security groups the user is a member of.
'   Call this function from your application startup code (in this sample: InitApplication.
'RETURNS:
'   True for success; False otherwise. If False we may not be on a domain.
Public Function CacheSecurityGroups() As Boolean
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Dim objRoot As ActiveDs.IADs        'Requires reference to "Active DS Type Library" (activeds.tlb)
    Dim objGroup As ActiveDs.IADsGroup
    Dim objUser As ActiveDs.IADsUser
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDNC As String               'DNC = Default Naming Context
    Dim strDomainName As String

    'The RootDse is a special LDAP object that exists on all LDAP v3 servers. With it you can write scripts that are independent of the domain or enterprise on which they are run.
    Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDNC = objRoot.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

    strDomainName = getUserDomain()
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomainName & "/" & getLoginName() & ",user")

    'Count number of groups
    i = 0
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Debug.Assert i > 0          'If user is in an Active Directory domain, (s)he should be a member of at least one group.
    ReDim m_strGroups(i - 1)    'Resize array so it can hold all groups.

    'Fill the array with group names
    i = 0
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        m_strGroups(i) = objGroup.Name
        Debug.Print objGroup.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    blnResult = True

Exit_Handler:
    CacheSecurityGroups = blnResult
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    blnResult = False
    If Err.Number = -2147023541 Then      '-2147023541 = Automation error. The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
        Err.Description = Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Found domain name: '" & strDomainName & "'. An empty domain name is indicative of the machine not being on a domain."
    End If
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

'PURPOSE:
'   Helper function to perform some fancy byte copying.
Private Function fStringFromPtr(lngPtr As Long) As String
    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim abytStr() As Byte

    lngLen = apiStrLenFromPtr(lngPtr) * 2
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)
        Call apiCopyMemory(abytStr(0), ByVal lngPtr, lngLen)
        fStringFromPtr = abytStr()
    End If
End Function
```

This code does not compile under 64 bit Access 2016, and the problem appears to stem from the Variant types I've declared. Here's what I've currently changed the code to:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim m_strGroups() As String         'Cache with all security groups this user is a member of.

Private Type WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
   wkui1_username As LongPtr     'current user name
   wkui1_logon_domain As LongPtr 'current user domain
   wkui1_oth_domains As LongPtr  'list of other LAN Manager domains browsed by the workstation
   wkui1_logon_server As LongPtr 'name of the computer that authenticated the server
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiWkStationUser Lib "Netapi32" Alias "NetWkstaUserGetInfo" (ByVal reserved As LongPtr, ByVal Level As LongPtr, bufptr As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiStrLenFromPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenW" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub apiCopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Function getLoginName() As String
    Dim ret As LongPtr
    Dim lpBuff As String * 255

    ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 255)

    If ret > 0 Then
        getLoginName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        getLoginName = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Public Function getUserDomain() As String
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim lngRet As LongPtr
    Dim lngPtr As LongPtr
    Dim tNTInfo As WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
    Dim strNTDomain As String

    lngRet = apiWkStationUser(0&, 1&, lngPtr)
    If lngRet = 0 Then
        Call apiCopyMemory(tNTInfo, ByVal lngPtr, LenB(tNTInfo))
        If Not lngPtr = 0 Then
            strNTDomain = fStringFromPtr(tNTInfo.wkui1_logon_domain)
        End If
    End If

Exit_Handler:
getUserDomain = strNTDomain
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    strNTDomain = vbNullString
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Public Function GetSecurityGroups() As String()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    CacheSecurityGroups

Exit_Handler:
    GetSecurityGroups = m_strGroups
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

'   Fills array with all Active Directory security groups the user is a member of.
'   Call this function from your application startup code (in this sample: InitApplication.
'RETURNS:
'   True for success; False otherwise. If False we may not be on a domain.
Public Function CacheSecurityGroups() As Boolean
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Dim objRoot As ActiveDs.IADs        'Requires reference to "Active DS Type Library" (activeds.tlb)
    Dim objGroup As ActiveDs.IADsGroup
    Dim objUser As ActiveDs.IADsUser
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDNC As String               'DNC = Default Naming Context
    Dim strDomainName As String

    'The RootDse is a special LDAP object that exists on all LDAP v3 servers. With it you can write scripts that are independent of the domain or enterprise on which they are run.
    Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDNC = objRoot.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

    strDomainName = getUserDomain()
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomainName & "/" & getLoginName() & ",user")

    'Count number of groups
    i = 0
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Debug.Assert i > 0          'If user is in an Active Directory domain, (s)he should be a member of at least one group.
    ReDim m_strGroups(i - 1)    'Resize array so it can hold all groups.

    'Fill the array with group names
    i = 0
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        m_strGroups(i) = objGroup.Name
        Debug.Print objGroup.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    blnResult = True

Exit_Handler:
    CacheSecurityGroups = blnResult
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    blnResult = False
    If Err.Number = -2147023541 Then      '-2147023541 = Automation error. The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
        Err.Description = Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Found domain name: '" & strDomainName & "'. An empty domain name is indicative of the machine not being on a domain."
    End If
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

'PURPOSE:
'   Helper function to perform some fancy byte copying.
Private Function fStringFromPtr(lngPtr As LongPtr) As String
    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim abytStr() As Byte

    lngLen = apiStrLenFromPtr(lngPtr) * 2
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)
        Call apiCopyMemory(abytStr(0), ByVal lngPtr, lngLen)
        fStringFromPtr = abytStr()
    End If
End Function
```

As indicated, the getLoginName function is returning the expected result. The Type Mismatch error currently appears in the fStringFromPtr function, and seems to be triggered by the ReDim statement.

Comment: Why even change to Access 64-bit?

Comment: The decision on what application to use is well above my head, I'm afraid. The firm is upgrading universally to 64 bit MS Office. My task is to make sure this one database application can operate under the new system. So far, everything works except for the Active Directory authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve Windows userID in VB for 64-bit/Access 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847583/how-to-retrieve-windows-userid-in-vb-for-64-bit-access-2013)

Comment: More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office, https://support.fmsinc.com/hc/en-us/articles/214566343-What-are-the-32-and-64-bit-versions-of-Microsoft-Access-2016-2013-and-2010-

Comment: The portions of the code that retrieve the user's login and domain appear to be working correctly. The most significant changes I've had to make so far are declaring Pointer variables as LongPtr rather than Long, and adding the PtrSafe tag to Declare statements. All of that appears to be working until the code reaches the ReDim statement. That's when the Type Mismatch comes up. But I can't figure out what Variable Type I should be using.

Comment: Have you tried Variant?

Comment: LongPtr is a Long on 32bit, and LongLong on 64bit. It's the LongLong that is causing the issue. Can you change lngLen to Long? Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009053)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: Please share the actual code you're using (which API calls are generating this string). You're likely doing it wrong and don't need the whole bytearray as buffer stuff but can immediately create a string buffer and not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out June7's suggestion to redefine lngLen as a Variant did the trick. The following code works under 64 bit:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim m_strGroups() As String         'Cache with all security groups this user is a member of.

Private Type WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
   wkui1_username As LongPtr     'current user name
   wkui1_logon_domain As LongPtr 'current user domain
   wkui1_oth_domains As LongPtr  'list of other LAN Manager domains browsed by the workstation
   wkui1_logon_server As LongPtr 'name of the computer that authenticated the server
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiWkStationUser Lib "Netapi32" Alias "NetWkstaUserGetInfo" (ByVal reserved As LongPtr, ByVal Level As LongPtr, bufptr As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiStrLenFromPtr Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenW" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub apiCopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Function getLoginName() As String
    Dim ret As LongPtr
    Dim lpBuff As String * 255

    ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 255)

    If ret > 0 Then
        getLoginName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        getLoginName = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Public Function getUserDomain() As String
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim lngRet As LongPtr
    Dim lngPtr As LongPtr
    Dim tNTInfo As WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
    Dim strNTDomain As String

    lngRet = apiWkStationUser(0&, 1&, lngPtr)
    If lngRet = 0 Then
        Call apiCopyMemory(tNTInfo, ByVal lngPtr, LenB(tNTInfo))
        If Not lngPtr = 0 Then
            strNTDomain = fStringFromPtr(tNTInfo.wkui1_logon_domain)
        End If
    End If

Exit_Handler:
getUserDomain = strNTDomain
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    strNTDomain = vbNullString
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Public Function GetSecurityGroups() As String()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    CacheSecurityGroups

Exit_Handler:
    GetSecurityGroups = m_strGroups
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

'   Fills array with all Active Directory security groups the user is a member of.
'   Call this function from your application startup code (in this sample: InitApplication.
'RETURNS:
'   True for success; False otherwise. If False we may not be on a domain.
Public Function CacheSecurityGroups() As Boolean
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Dim objRoot As ActiveDs.IADs        'Requires reference to "Active DS Type Library" (activeds.tlb)
    Dim objGroup As ActiveDs.IADsGroup
    Dim objUser As ActiveDs.IADsUser
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDNC As String               'DNC = Default Naming Context
    Dim strDomainName As String

    'The RootDse is a special LDAP object that exists on all LDAP v3 servers. With it you can write scripts that are independent of the domain or enterprise on which they are run.
    Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    strDNC = objRoot.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

    strDomainName = getUserDomain()
    Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomainName & "/" & getLoginName() & ",user")

    'Count number of groups
    i = 0
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Debug.Assert i > 0          'If user is in an Active Directory domain, (s)he should be a member of at least one group.
    ReDim m_strGroups(i - 1)    'Resize array so it can hold all groups.

    'Fill the array with group names
    i = 0
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        m_strGroups(i) = objGroup.Name
        Debug.Print objGroup.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    blnResult = True

Exit_Handler:
    CacheSecurityGroups = blnResult
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    blnResult = False
    If Err.Number = -2147023541 Then      '-2147023541 = Automation error. The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
        Err.Description = Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Found domain name: '" & strDomainName & "'. An empty domain name is indicative of the machine not being on a domain."
    End If
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

'PURPOSE:
'   Helper function to perform some fancy byte copying.
Private Function fStringFromPtr(lngPtr As LongPtr) As String
    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim abytStr() As Byte

    lngLen = apiStrLenFromPtr(lngPtr) * 2
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)
        Call apiCopyMemory(abytStr(0), ByVal lngPtr, lngLen)
        fStringFromPtr = abytStr()
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, the problem appears to be the "ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)" instruction. This has been resulting in a Type Mismatch error

wants to tell you that an array can't have a`LongPtr`( what may get`LongLong`on x64 vba) as dimension. Maximum is`Long`!

This could be fixed by a [type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) to`Long`with:

```vb
ReDim abytStr(0 To CLng(lngLen) - 1)
```

But your initial fault is the wrong x64 API Declaration! Read [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit) and for [lstrlenW](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-DE/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lstrlenw), the length of the string returned should stay a`Long`type. Only`lpString`needs to be changed to`LongPtr`as it is a pointer to the string. I recommend [Windows API Viewer for MS Excel](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm) for conversions. If some delarations are mising (like`lstrlenW`) check the ms api docs for the c++ syntax data types and adapt them.

Fixed API declaration`apiStrLenFromPtr`:

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiStrLenFromPtr Lib "kernel32" _
                        Alias "lstrlenW" (ByVal lpString As LongPtr) As Long
```

Fixed function`fStringFromPtr`:

```vb
Private Function fStringFromPtr(lngPtr As LongPtr) As String
    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim abytStr() As Byte

    lngLen = apiStrLenFromPtr(lngPtr) * 2
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ReDim abytStr(0 To lngLen - 1)
...
```

Check and fix all your wrong API declarations and change calling code to fit.