# Microsoft access 2013 edit permission

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to have a access file which is for a number of user to enter new entries at the same time, but each user would not be able to see or edit what other have entered but they have their own permissions to edit their own record.

The admin user has full ability to supervise all the entries.

I believe this is to do with permission control, and I have got some idea but not sure which one is the best approach

1. set up a db which contain the list of approved user and password and user will be needing to log in within the access file before reaching the db entering page
2. to use system permission control facility but I have no idea how to get it work

Would someone please make some suggestion about how I could achieve this?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you capture the Windows User ID and store that in your table.  You can then configure your form to filter records for that specific user.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677112/how-to-get-logged-in-users-name-in-access-vba) for ideas on how to do that.

I personally would avoid methods 1 and 2 that you list in your question, in favor of customizing the form to filter records for that specific user.

For the administrative user, you would need to configure the form "not" to filter for that user.