# How to get the process ID of the current Excel instance, through VBA, without using the caption?

Tags: excel, vba, pid

How can I get the process ID of the current Excel instance that my VBA code is running in? I don't want to asking for it by the name in the caption, which causes problems when I have two or more Excel instances with the same caption.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this method to get the current process id.

```
Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
```

[This page](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=366892&seqNum=3) has a good overview of exactly how you can do it in various versions of excel.

Comment: Works great; note that in VBA object modules (e.g., in a module associated with an Excel workbook), you must prefix the declaration with `Private `.

Comment: @mklement0 this is wrong for at least for `Excel 2010`, nevertheless if one wants to call it differently one has to wrap it in another function and thus `private` could make sense

Comment: @AndreasDietrich From at least 2013 on, from what I can tell, you _must_ use `Private` in _object_ modules (those associated with the workbook as a whole or a given worksheet, under "Microsoft Excel Objects" in the VBA project view, but _not_ in _code-only_ modules (under "Modules"). Additionally, in VBA 7 (not sure what version that corresponds to, but it is the case in Excel 2019), you must use the `PtrSafe` attribute (`Private Declare PtrSafe Function ...`). So, how does it work in Excel 2010 and below?

Comment: @mklement0 ah - thx for the clarification. I was talking then about *code-only* modules.

Answer (score 3):

As a vba n00b, some other things I did not know

1. The Declare statement goes at the top. VBA will complain if the declare statement is inserted after a sub declaration

   For example, this will work

   ```
   Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

   Sub Update
     ...
     ...
   End Sub
   ```

   But this will not work

   ```
   Sub Update
     ...
     ...
   End Sub

   Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
   ```
2. Here is how we display the PID in a messagebox in vbscript

   ```
   Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   MsgBox("Excel PID is " + CStr(app.Run("GetCurrentProcessId")))
   ```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 3):

My solution in Excel 2013: in a new module, I added the following code:

```
Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetCurrentProcessId
End Sub
```