# Use a variable for an Application name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that will switch between programs. I've noticed that Excel 2010 and 2016 are named differently in the system (my semantics here are wrong, sorry!) and instead of having to change the code depending on which Excel, I was just thinking I could use a variable to set that.

```
Sub test()
'code here in Excel

Dim myApp
myApp = Application.Application
AppActivate "Google Chrome"
Call AppActivate("Google Chrome")
' do one or two things

AppActivate myApp
'do more things in Excel
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the `AppActivate myApp` doesn't work. It throws

> Run-time Error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Is there a way to do what I'm trying? I see on [this site](http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/appactivate-activate-folder-or-application-if-already-open/) that I could do something like:

```
Public vPID As Variant
vPID = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate (vPID)
```

Except, what if Excel isn't located in the same file path on the two computers it's going to be used on?

Edit: It looks like I just need to set the `Title` of the Application to the variable (again, from that site):

> Normally, the AppActivate statement is used to activate an existing application based on its title.

edit2: Getting closer, I found I could get the path to `Excel.Exe` by this, `excelPath = Application.Path & "\Excel.exe"` but can't figure out how to call that.

Comment: Not clear......do you want to **open** an instance of Word or **activate** an instance that you have already opened ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I want it to activate an instance that is already open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To activate by the window title of the instance running the code:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

Or by Process ID (likely more robust):

```
AppActivate pid
```

Where `pid` is the result of [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942058/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-the-current-excel-throught-vba-without-relying-on).

Comment: Aha! Using the `.Caption` did the trick.  I'll look into the `pid` part as well.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example of:

1. opening Word
2. activating it

   ```
   Sub UsingWord()
   Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

   Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   wrdApp.Visible = True
   AppActivate wrdApp.Caption
   End Sub
   ```